# What specific symbols can't contain <xs:string> validation element?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

Do we have any special symbols in filed with  attr, which can prevent successful validation of xml document, and what type of attribute doesn't have any restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood the question correctly, but an attribute declared with type="xs:string" can contain any character that is legal in XML. This excludes some things such as control characters (e.g. x00), unmatched surrogates, etc: the exact details vary between XML 1.0 and XML 1.1.